# How to pass an int data with an intent?

Tags: android, android-room

Hi I'm doing a project and I'm using room persistence to manage my database but when I get the id from my activity to pass it to another activity for edit the data it gives that incompatible types

Here is my DaoClass, I want to call getOne methos

```
 @Insert
void insert(Entradas entradas);

@Update
void update(Entradas entradas);

@Delete
void delete(Entradas entradas);

@Query("DELETE FROM Entradas")
void deleteAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Entradas")
LiveData<List<Entradas>> getAll();  

@Query("SELECT * FROM Entradas WHERE IdEntrada ==:Id")
LiveData<Entradas> getOne(int Id);
```

Here is my activity, when I'm using the methos longClickListener to sent me to another activity

```
        adapter.addActionCallback(new EntradasAdapter.ActionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClickListener(Entradas entradas) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateEntradaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(UpdateEntradaActivity.EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID,  entradas.getIdEntrada());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And this the activity that I want to show the data

```
public static String EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID = "IdEntrada";

private Button btnCalendario, btnCrear;
private EditText etNombre, etSaldo;
private TextView etFecha;
Calendar c;
DatePickerDialog dpd;
private CategoriaEntradasViewModel viewModel;
private CuentasViewModel viewModel1;
private EntradasViewModel viewModel2;
Spinner spinner, spinner1;
List<CategoriaEntradas> categoriaEntradas1;
List<Cuentas> cuentas1;
private EntradasDao mEntradasDAO;
private Entradas ENTRADAS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_entrada);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>"+"Editar Entrada"+"</font>"));
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mEntradasDAO = Room.databaseBuilder(this, Database.class, "Database")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()       //Allows room to do operation on main thread
            .build()
            .entradasDao();

    final Context ctx = this;
    etNombre= findViewById(R.id.editText);
    etSaldo= findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    etFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
    btnCalendario= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFecha);
    btnCrear = findViewById(R.id.btnCrear);



    ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID));
}
```

The error is in the last line `ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID));`

it says `getOne(int) in EntradasDao cannot be applied to java.lang.String`

Answer (score 2):

You are putting as Int and while reading trying get as String.
Replace

```
    mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID));
with 
    mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID,0));
```

Comment: Now it says Incompatible types 
Required: Entities.Entradas
Found: lifecycle.LiveData

Answer (score 0):

The way to read that message is "the method `getOne()` accepts an `int`, but you are passing a `java.lang.String`". So you have to figure out why the value you're passing is a `String`.

> ```
> ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID));
> ```

In your case, though, this is pretty straightforward. You are passing it the value of a `getStringExtra()` call, which is always going to be a `String`.

There are two paths forward to fixing this. Which you choose will depend on whether or not the value you're putting into the `Intent` is actually a `String` or an `int`.

> ```
> intent.putExtra(UpdateEntradaActivity.EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID,  entradas.getIdEntrada());
> ```

If `entradas.getIdEntrada()` is an `int`, then you can change the other side of things to simply retrieve an `int` extra:

```
ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID, 0));
```

If `entradas.getIdEntrada()` is a `String`, then you will have to change the other side to retrieve the `String` and then parse it to an `int`

```
String idString = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID);
int idInt = Integer.parseInt(idString);
ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(idInt);
```

## Edit

As mentioned in comments, the return value of the `getOne()` method is a `LiveData<Entradas>`, not just an `Entradas`. While this is not the recommended way to use `LiveData`, for the purposes of this question you can retrieve the value by calling `getValue()`.

```
int idInt = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID, 0);
ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(idInt).getValue();
```

```
String idString = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ENTRADA_ID);
int idInt = Integer.parseInt(idString);
ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(idInt).getValue();
```

Comment: Now it says Incompatible types Required: Entities.Entradas Found: lifecycle.LiveData

Comment: How a `LiveData` object works is outside the scope of this question, but you can get the current value of the `LiveData` by calling `getValue()`. So you can say `ENTRADAS = mEntradasDAO.getOne(idInt).getValue();`

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting null in the other activity